# What is the Chern number of twisted bilayer graphene without hBN substrate?

Tags: topology, graphene

I am approaching at the study of topological materials and I need help to understand the role of Berry curvature in the twisted bilayer graphene.

The raise up of the Moire lattice and consequently the related Moire Brillouin zone (or mini BZ) implies always the time-reversal symmetry. In addition there is energy gap in the band structure of the system and this band gap is related to the tunnelling between the 2 layers and among moire unit cells.
My question is: what about the Berry curvature in the twisted bilayer graphene? Is it this system alone becoming a topological insulator with Chern number non null?
I know that once the twisted bilayer graphene is on top of hBN, due to the breaking of the inversion symmetry, the system becomes topological.

Thank you for the help